# MD5 Python Brute Force Error

Tags: python, python-2.7, hash, md5

I have been coding with python for a while now and decided to make an MD5 brute forcer. This is my code here

```
import hashlib
import sys
import os
import time
import urllib2
import urllib
import re
import string 
import random
from itertools import islice

string = raw_input("HASH TO DECRYPT: ")

size = input("PASSWORD LENGTH: ")

char_list = ("a")

def random_char(size):
    selection = iter(lambda: random.choice(char_list),object())
    while True:
        yield ''.join(islice(selection, size))
random_gen = random_char(size) 

def encrypt(random_gen):
    algorithim = hashlib.md5()
    algorithim.update(random_gen)
    encrypted=algorithim.hexdigest()



def dosethestringexisit():
    if encrypt(random_gen) == string :
        print next(random_char)
    else:
        print("pass not found")

print dosethestringexisit()
```

I've had a couple of issues such as this error

```
  algorithim.update(random_gen)
TypeError: must be string or buffer, not generator
```

I don't know how to change the random produced string to fit in the algorithm.update().

Note the char list is only "a" because i used md5 a hash of "a" just to test if the code worked.

Also I was wondering how to make a while loop to repeat the code if the random hash does not equal the hash that needs to be decrypted. Many Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get a item from a generator, you need to use `next` function:

```
def encrypt(random_gen):
    algorithim = hashlib.md5()
    algorithim.update(next(random_gen))
    encrypted=algorithim.hexdigest()
```

You can also use `next` method (or `__next__` method in Python 3.x):

```
algorithim.update(random_gen.next())
```

Above will resolve the exception.

BTW, the code is using `string` as a variable name. That shadows the module `string`; prevent use of the module. Use different variable name.

---

Brute force means try all possible inputs; instead of using random, using [`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.product), you can get all strings:

```
>>> import hashlib
>>> import itertools
>>> import string
>>>
>>> def dosethestringexisit(target, size):
...     for xs in itertools.product(string.ascii_letters, repeat=size):
...         s = ''.join(xs)
...         if hashlib.md5(s).hexdigest() == target:
...             return s
...
>>> dosethestringexisit('912ec803b2ce49e4a541068d495ab570', 4)
'asdf'
```

Comment: I fixed the first two issues but I do not understand the last bit of information you gave me. what would the code look like with the itertools.product code you mentioned.

Comment: @Amedeo, I updated the answer to include `itertools.product`. Are you seeing old version of my answer? Try `for xs in itertools.product('abc', repeat=2): print(''.join(xs))` to get what `itertools.product` does.

Comment: I saw you answer with the inter tools.product but i do not understand where to place it in my code.

Comment: @Amedeo, The function `dosethestringexisit` itself is what you want. Isn't it? The function will return the original string or `None` if it can't find the match.

Comment: I edited my origional question and changed the code, is that what the code should look like? Because if it is its producing the result as none?

Comment: I visited the paste bin, i copied the code. i used the letter "a" in md5 hash and it outputs none?

Comment: What's the your md5 hex digest string and the original string?

Comment: original string is "a" hex digest is "0cc175b9c0f1b6a831c399e269772661"

Comment: @Amedeo, The code gave me `a` as expected. See this: http://asciinema.org/a/14342

Comment: I re copied the paste bin code in raw paste and the code worked, thank you for your help. Much appreciated!